# moodle auth using contextid in array

Tags: php, arrays, authentication, moodle

Can anyone shed any light as to why this is not working:

`$USER->id` is the logged in user.

```
  $contextroles = get_records_sql("SELECT userid FROM {$CFG->prefix}role_assignments WHERE contextid = 23 AND roleid = 3");
        
        if (in_array($USER->id, $contextroles)) {
        echo'your in<br />';
        echo $USER->id.'<br />';
        print_r($contextroles);
        }
        
        else{
        echo'Access denied<br />';
        echo $USER->id.'<br />';
        print_r($contextroles);
        }
```

This is the output:

> Access denied
>
> 5410
>
> Array ( [7] => stdClass Object ( [userid] => 7 ) [9] => stdClass Object ( [userid] => 9 ) [27] => stdClass Object ( [userid] => 27 ) [98] => stdClass Object ( [userid] => 98 ) [203] => stdClass Object ( [userid] => 203 ) [252] => stdClass Object ( [userid] => 252 ) [5410] => stdClass Object ( [userid] => 5410 ) )

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$contextroles is an array of objects and the needle you are searching is within the object. in_array cannot handle objects and hence it fails. You can use the following code snippet to get the desired results:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php#105937